# Using JsonExtractor Value in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have like 3 JsonExtractors in a single thread. How do i use the value extracted from the first to the third ?

The first JsonExtractor extracts 'winSpoke' value from the response json and i am storing in as

> Names of created variables: WinSpoke

The third JsonExtractor will extract 'payLevelDetails' value based on the previous WinSpoke value and i am storing in as

> Names of created variables: PayLevelDetails 
>   Json Path expressions: $.payLevels[${WinSpoke}]

However i am getting error as -

> JSONPostProcessor: Error processing JSON content in Pay Level Details
>   JSON Extractor, message: Could not parse token starting at position
>   11. Expected ?, ', 0-9, *

Can someone help me in pointing where i might have gone wrong ?

Comment: Can you show the json path you use for getting `WinSpoke`?

Comment: The path is - $.winSpoke which is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup should work just fine given you have `${WinSpoke}` variable defined, you can double check its value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)

[image]

[image]

Also be aware that [PostProcessors are being executed **upside down**](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) so make sure that the JSON Extractor which extracts your `WinSpoke` variable is **above** the one which is referencing the variable.

Comment: Yes the JSON Extractor which extracts the WinSpoke variable is above the one which is referencing the variable, but i still get the error. Interestingly if i replace the '${WinSpoke}' reference to any hard coded integer, the error goes off. I guess it is not storing the value inside WinSpoke variable in the first JsonExtractor. Cant figure it out why

Comment: JMeter doesn't have any problems with using variables in JSONPath extractor as it evidenced by above screenshots, you need to figure out why your extractor doesn't extract your WinSpoke variable properly

Comment: Okay got it. I am able to see the intended values in 'DebugSampler', but still in the console it displaying the same json parse error, dnt know why. Thanks anyways Sir

Comment: I got the value as intended but how do i increment/decrement the value of '${WinSpoke}' ? I tried using like $.payLevels[${WinSpoke} - 1] but it failed. Is WinSpoke variable storing the value in string format ? If so how to make it behave like an Integer ?